# Javascript property is defined, but returns undefined

Tags: javascript, rxjs, redux-observable

I have this JSON object:

```
{
  "type": "SIGN_IN",
  "credentials": {
    "id": "mt@ft.cc",
    "password": "jhkl"
  }
}
```

When I log `obj.cedentials`, it shows the same object (as obj);

```
{
  "type": "SIGN_IN",
  "credentials": {
    "id": "mt@ft.cc",
    "password": "jhkl"
  }
}
```

When I try to access id, like: `obj.credentials.id`, it returns undefined

[image]

Why is this happening? Is it evaluated later?

Comment: Did you try `obj.credentials.credentials.id`?

Answer (score 3):

Your `credentials` object contains a `credentials` object.

So you need to use the following:

```
console.log(obj.credentials.credentials.id);
```

The full content of your `obj` variable is actually the following:

```
{
    "credentials": {
        "type": "SIGN_IN",
        "credentials": {
            "id": "mt@ft.cc",
            "password": "jhkl"
        }
    },
    "type": "SIGN_IN",
    ...
}
```

Comment: yo dawg, heard you like credentials

Answer (score 3):

Your object seems to look like this:

```
q = {
    credentials: {
        credentials: { ...id }
    }
}
```

so to access the id you need to use: `q.credentials.credentials.id`

Answer (score 0):

> When I log obj.cedentials, it's shows same object (same as obj);
>
> ```
> {
>   "type": "SIGN_IN",
>   "credentials": {
>     "id": "mt@ft.cc",
>     "password": "jhkl"
>   }
> }
> ```

So when you log `obj.cedentials` you get an object which has a `credentials` property containing an object which has an `id` property.

`obj.cedentials` does not have an `id` property of its own!

You need `obj.cedentials.credentials.id`.

Comment: ,typo `credentials` rather than `cedentials`. I think it was a typo in the OP that you borrowed.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
console.log(q.credentials.credentials.id);
```